# What evidence is there that Jesus went to India?

Tags: ancient-history, india

Do we have any historical evidence that Jesus visited India? What is the evidence and the source for the belief held by many people in India that the Roza Bal shrine is the tomb of Jesus?

Comment: Although this question isn't off-topic, it's probably more suited to skeptics.SE than here.

Comment: Vote to close. Unless there is some research that shows that Jesus visited India, or Idaho, or .... whatever.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Before writing questions off to Skeptics.SE, I strongly recommend checking out their [introduction](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1505/15087). They have different rules which make this question as-is not a good fit for their site.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - the OP, who appears to be in India, is obviously citing sources that he heard about or read regarding this subject in his native land. IMO that is sufficient to warrant historical investigation.

Comment: Jesus is undeniably the most important single figure in the history of the Western World. Why should a question regarding interesting and important aspects of his life not be appropriate for this site? The question is clearly historical in nature, not 'social science' (whatever that is...) and not religious. To declare this question as 'off topic' seems completely unwarranted IMO.

Comment: How is this not about History? It's a valid question about the doings of a famous person. Per the [help center](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions about famous people are on-topic here.

Comment: @Vector Off-topic: theology.

Comment: @SamuelRussell - as explained, there is nothing theological here, nor is there in my answer. Although Jesus is a biblical figure, that does not mean that all discussion about him becomes theological. This is a question about where the man traveled and where he is buried, that's all.

Comment: @Vector http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historicity_of_Jesus , "Virtually all modern scholars of antiquity agree that Jesus existed, and although there is little agreement on the historicity of gospel narratives and their theological assertions of his divinity"  The question is not historical.

Comment: @SamuelRussell-I still don't get it: Are you trying to say that even though we know he existed, he can't be deemed a historically important figure such that we should discuss his life, because it's possible that his historical impact is myth based? Or perhaps you mean that it is impossible to answer because we have no reliable source except the Gospels, which are questionable historical sources unless we accept the theological premise that they are accurate as written? You yourself agree that he existed, and you cannot deny that he had huge historical impact, so what's the problem?

Comment: @SamuelRussell - BTW, 'I have no dog in this race'. I am not a Christian and I simply enjoyed dealing with a question that I found provocative from a historical perspective.

Comment: This would be better discussed through chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10242/discussion-between-vector-and-samuel-russell)

Comment: Yesterday the question was on hold since it doesn't show any researches from my side, I agree, I didn't do more researches on topic. But, I don't find a reason to be declared this question as off topic. Also the question is about a man who is founder of a religion. So the answer will certainly have some of the points of views from religion and it is also part of the history. Also this is related to history of India. When considering the history of India, the question will get more broad. So as for now I stick to this question only.

Comment: @vector: I can't participate in the discussions as for now, and I am having an eye on this anyway.

Comment: One more thing, I asked a similar question in christianity.se(http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18138/where-was-jesus-from-his-age-12-to-33), but I was not satisfied with the answers as those were purely based on Bible. Where else should I ask the question to know about this if the question is  not answered in History.SE?

Comment: @arun: The highest votes answer on christianity.SE is not based on the bible, and I think it's a very well argued answer for how unlikely the claims are. As such I'm not voting to reopen this, it seem (against my prejudiced expectations) that christianity.SE is an excellent place to ask this question.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: In christianity.se it is answered well,but I have a different question here, the question is slightly different and I hope, that difference make this question to be asked in History.se. Also please see the added link in the question.

Comment: @arun: This question is about the claims he want to India *after* his death. Jayarathina Madharasan who answered your first question hints that he is fully prepared to answer that question as well. It's a fantastic answer, and you should accept it immediately.

Comment: @arun as it's already answered there, you have your answer. We're not here to stroke your vanity and provide you with an answer that better matches your preconceptions if you don't like the one you got already (which no doubt it "almost certainly not, even if he existed").

Comment: @arun -  "Also this is related to history of India" Good point - that is certainly not theological. You want to know what is the historical nature of an ancient tomb in your home country that has many interesting stories surrounding it. That is IMO a very good reason for consider this question historical.

Comment: @arun - "Also the question is about a man who is founder of a religion"-that claim is not supportable historically - it is purely theological. The most history can say is that Jesus taught a 'reformed' sort of Judaism. And many dispute that - if you go to the discussions you will see. I think this question can certainly be admitted here because Jesus was a famous person in history (some also dispute that) and also because of your argument about the history of India. That is sufficient IMO to re-open this question.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: what he answered is true in one perspective, but I am curious about the other sides of the question also. In that answer it is stated like this, "There are absolutely no concrete evidence. Absolutely nothing!!", I want to clarify this, That's why I asked "What evidence is there that Jesus went to India?" in history.se. Surely, I can not get and ask for more evidences on this in christianity.se. Also I just don't want you people to concentrate on that bbc link in the question. It's just a finding of my google search.

Comment: @jwenting: It is answered well in there, but this question have another view,it can not be the answer for this question. I just pointed out that question  to show that I have done some search on the same. In a historical perspective I don't find any reasons for not to ask this question here. I would have asked this question here first, but I was a little late in finding this one. Please don't mix up those questions.

Comment: @arun: That answer is the correct answer. There is absolutely no evidence for it. It's clear from your response that you asked the question here because you did not like the answer you got. But that answer is correct, and there really isn't any other perspectives. Reality may suck, but you have to deal with it anyway.

Comment: BBC link goes here from there :http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/programmes/from_our_own_correspondent/8587838.stm

Comment: @LennartRegebro:You are right,but I found the answer in history.se is more acceptable than that. Historians need to have more research on this anyway.

Comment: Now also I don't see any reason to be declared this as an off topic. Need to specify the reason...

Comment: @arun "need to have more research" when the claim is utterly discredited? There's no need for more research, there is nothing to research. You're trying to stroke your vanity (or your national ego) again by disregarding the facts you don't like.

Comment: @jwenting: The discussions on hidden years of Jesus will be lengthy anyway. I had some doubts on that answer and it is not cleared enough for me to accept that.(you may call it vanity or whatever). And as you said, here is nothing to research on these doubts, those are really off topic.

Comment: The question should rather be "What proof do we have that this person even existed?"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The recent written source for the idea that Jesus is buried at Roza Bal is here: [Jesus in India - by Mirza Ghulam Ahmad - The Discovery.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_India_%28book%29#The_discovery) No forensic evidence seems to be cited. Ahmad relied on his own personal research of the subject and older Islamic traditions, oral and written.

As for Jesus visiting India during his life, See: [Nicolas Notovitch: Notovitch is known for his 1887 book claiming that during his unknown years, Jesus left Galilee for India and studied with Buddhists and Hindus there before returning to Judea,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Notovitch) although Notovitch himself (based on the wiki - I have not read the book) never claimed Jesus was buried in India or Kashmir but traveled there and then returned to Palestine. *(Thanks to @LennartRegebro for this reference.)*

But Notovitch is a problematic source: He later admitted that his story was essentially a fabrication, and as a European writing in Europe, it's unlikely that he was the source of those beliefs you refer to. Perhaps the writings of [Swami Abhedananda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Abhedananda): [Although Notovitch had been discredited in Europe, Swami Abhedananda wrote a book called Journey to Kashmir and Tibet in which he stated that had visited Hemis and seen a document similar to the one Notovitch had mentioned, and produced a Bengali translation of parts of it,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Notovitch#Allegations_of_forgery_and_confession) are better sources for this idea.

**Regarding the validity of the claim that the Roza Bal Shrine is Jesus's tomb:** In light of the extensive biblical testimony that Jesus was entombed in ancient Palestine, [Resurrection of Jesus, Burial,Resurrection of Jesus, Tomb Discovery,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_of_Jesus#Tomb_discovery)  one would need to explain how Jesus's body ended up in Kashmir. But if we accept the biblical account of the Resurrection, it is possible to say that once he was resurrected he could have ended up anywhere. But again, this is contradicted by the biblical account: [His final appearance is reported as being forty days after the resurrection when he ascended into heaven[Lk. 24:44–49] where he remains with God the Father and God the Holy Spirit until the Second Coming of Christ.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_of_Jesus#Resurrection_appearances_of_Jesus)

Whether or not we accept the biblical account of the Resurrection, the numerous biblical references and their persistence would seem to put the burden of proof on Ahmad and his sources, and the evidence does not appear to weigh in their favor, particularly since we have other sources besides the New Testament attesting that Jesus lived and died in Palestine. If so, a very good explanation must be offered as to how his body ended up in Kashmir, thousands of miles away.

Comment: Well, that's only part of the source. [Notovich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Notovitch) was first with his claim that Jesus during the "missing years" of his story in the bible went to India and encountered Buddhism.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - Although there is some pertinent information there, Notovitch later admitted that his story was essentially a fabrication, and as European writing in Europe, it's unlikely that he was the source of those legends. IMO the work of [Swami Abhedananda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Abhedananda) mentioned in your source, is probably more relevant. Still, I have cited your source in my answer, with due credit.

Comment: Unexplained down-votes are counter-productive. Please state your reasons, so the answer can be improved.

Comment: It's not my downvote, but something you could state as criticism is that the biblical story doesn't really contradict the India-stories. This is intentional on the authors of the india-stories, they have tried to merge the two. The assumption on the part of Ahmad is for example that Jesus resurrection is explained by him in fact not dying, and that he after recovering travelled to India. The only thing that contradicts that in the Bible is Jesus ascent into heaven, something that requires religion to believe in, and as such isn't really admissible as scientific evidence.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - OK Lennart, I will take you at your word. I did address somewhat the point you mention but you have gone further. Note: 1) The Bible says Jesus died - that's a contradiction to Ahmad. 2) Leaving the religion out of it, the Bible does say quite clearly there that **he's not buried in India.**

Comment: It's hard to keep religion out of that statement, as it in fact states that he is alive. Ignoring religion the bible doesn't state anything about his final resting place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10225/discussion-between-vector-and-lennart-regebro)

Comment: @Vector the bible makes no claims about him not being burried anywhere. It only makes a claim about him ascending to the heavens, without stating whether that is to be considered his body or his soul (most people take it to mean the latter).

Comment: @jwenting: If only his soul went up to heaven, that would seem to leave his body in Judea, no? And if we discount the bible story about his being taken to heaven, that also leaves him in Judea.

Comment: @Vector it says nothing about where the body went, that's the whole point. It doesn't make it impossible for the body to have ended up in India, or on Mars, or in Lalaland.

Comment: @jwenting - "It doesn't make it impossible" - didn't say it was impossible. just saying that the assumption would be that the body didn't go anywhere, unless you can prove otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

There is no historical or primary textual evidence that I am aware of which stated that Jesus ever traveled to India. I heard and read about this claim over the years and it seems to be more mythical and less historical.  Now even though there is no major historical or primary textual evidence proving that Jesus traveled to India, does not entirely exclude the possibility that Jesus traveled to India.

If one looks at the 4 Gospels in terms of Jesus' travels, we are told that his travels were regional, that is to say, not beyond the Middle East.  In contemporary terms, Jesus lived and traveled in present-day Israel, the Palestinian West Bank-(then called, Judea and Samaria), Jordan, as well as Egypt.  It is possible that Jesus may have traveled to the town of Tyre in Southern Lebanon or perhaps around Southern Syria-(which was in fairly close proximity to the Galilee). However, the 4 Gospels, to my recollection, do not mention other or additional lands that Jesus traveled to-(besides the Middle East region).

I don't remember any the of Apocraphyl stories mentioning Jesus' travels beyond the Middle East as well; nor is there any mentioning of Jesus traveling to India-(or other lands beyond the Middle East) in The Letters and Acts of The New Testament.  Flavis Josephus' short discussion on Jesus, to my knowledge, does not contain Jesus' travel itinerary.  These are some of the earliest historical sources we have on Jesus and all of them were written a generation and generations after his death.

Admittedly, I am not well versed in the Ancient Literature of India, which may have some interesting primary documentation proving such a claim, though I am currently unaware of such texts and sources.

As to whether or not Jesus is entombed in the Roza Bal Shrine, it is similar to claims that Jesus is entombed at the Talpiot Cave in Jerusalem or that Jesus was originally enshrined in the Garden Tomb in Jerusalem as well.  And of course there is the Church of the Holy Sepulcher in Jerusalem which has had its own lore for nearly 2000 years.  In other words, the enshrinement and entombment of Jesus has produced-(and I expect will continue to produce), more stories and extraordinary claims thereby furthering its lore and mystique..........which is outside the realm of history and archaeology.

Comment: Actually, we can say that the accepted story among his followers fifty years after his death was that he was buried in a specific, known location in Jerusalem, rose from the dead and ascended into heaven.  That some of this is dismissed as myth by some people doesn't change the fact that his followers were apparently unaware of any travels to India (or to England's green and pleasant land...). Those stories first appear *much* later. This is not conclusive -- how could it be for any ancient figure? -- but a betting man knows which side to wager on before sending a time machine to check.